# Dismiss does not work correctly UIScrollView and UITableView

Tags: swift, uiscrollview, uikit, uiscrollviewdelegate

I have a UIViewController class that is presented over full screen
On it I have a scrollview and a stackview with a uiview and a table

```
view.addSubview(scrollView)
scrollView.addSubview(stackView)
stackView.addArrangedSubview(view1)
stackView.addArrangedSubview(tableView)
```

scrollView has a TapGestureRecognizer

```
func settings() {
    let gestureRec = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(close))
    gestureRec.cancelsTouchesInView = false
    gestureRec.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
    gestureRec.delegate = self
    
    scrollView.addGestureRecognizer(gestureRec)
}

@objc func close() {
    dismiss(animated: false)
}
```

Now if you click on any place, the screen closes, even if it is a tableView, how can I fix it? The screen needs to be closed only when you click on scroll, the table inside StackView should work fine

I tried to work with UIGestureRecognizer Delegate,override methods, determine the location of the tap

Comment: Why would tapping on a scroll view dismiss? This is unexpected behaviour to most users. Why not just have a navigation bar with a dismiss button as suggested here https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/patterns/modality/


Always give people an obvious way to dismiss a modal view. In general, it works well to follow the platform conventions people already know. For example, in iOS, iPadOS, and watchOS apps, people typically expect to find a button in the navigation bar or swipe down; in macOS and tvOS apps, people expect to find a button in the main content view.

Comment: @BrandonStillitano  I am creating custom Context Menu with reactions ( as in the Telegram or iMessage)

Comment: so then it should be up to the button/view that you tap to send the reaction to either dismiss the parent view or delegate back to the host view that it should dismiss. Tapping the scrollview itself though should not cause the dismissal.

Answer (score 0):

From what I gathered from your question, you have a parent view (scroll view) and a child view (stack view), and you only want to perform an action when the user taps on the parent view and not its children.

One solution you can try is to override [`gestureRecognizer:shouldReceiveTouch:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uigesturerecognizerdelegate/1624214-gesturerecognizer) and return `true` if the touch is in the desired place. Here's an example:

```swift
func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldReceive touch: UITouch)
  -> Bool
{
  return touch.view?.isEqual(scrollView) ?? false
}
```

Another way is to use [`hitTest(_:with:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622469-hittest) to determine the farthest descendant of the receiver in the view hierarchy (including itself) that contains the specified point (in our case, the touch). For your use case, if `hitTest` returns the scroll view, then you can confidently say that the user did not tap on the stack view. Here's an example:

```swift
func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldReceive touch: UITouch)
  -> Bool
{
  let hitView = scrollView.hitTest(touch.location(in: scrollView), with: nil)
  return hitView?.isEqual(scrollView) ?? false
}
```

Hope this helps!